# Mat Accordion open and close not working dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to open and close my `mat-accordion` dynamically however it is not working. The component is created so that it can be re-used.

Here is my code

*side-panel-accordian.component.html*

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="data.panelOpenState === true" (closed)="data.panelOpenState === false">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{ data?.title }}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

*side-panel-accordian.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidePanelAccordianData } from './side-panel-accordian.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-panel-accordian',
  templateUrl: './side-panel-accordian.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-panel-accordian.component.scss']
})
export class SidePanelAccordianComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: SidePanelAccordianData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

*side-panel-accordian.model.ts*

```
export class SidePanelAccordianData {
  public title: string = '';
  public panelOpenState: boolean;

  constructor(args) {
    this.title = args.title;
    this.panelOpenState = args.panelOpenState;
  }
}
```

*HTML file where I am trying to use the component*

```
<app-side-panel-accordian [data]="{title:'test text', panelOpenState: true}">
  <label class="inner-row-header">test text</label>
  <div class="inner-row-data">
    <p>test text</p>
  </div>
</app-side-panel-accordian>
```

So I am expecting that the accordion should be in an opened state when I get to the page because I am setting `panelOpenState: true`. However this is not happening.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you are wiring up code to the `<mat-expansion-panel>` `(opened)` and `(closed)` events.  This means your code will fire when the panel is opened or closed.  This does not set the state of the panel.

Instead you should bind your `panelOpenState` property to the `<mat-expansion>` element's `expanded` property:

```js
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="data.panelOpenState">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{ data?.title }}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```